In desktop, Flutter Listener onPointerSignal method can not get the wheel deltaY
Here is the code below:
body: Center(
        child: Listener(
          onPointerSignal: (PointerEvent event) {
            print('result is ${event is PointerScrollEvent}, ${event is PointerScaleEvent}, ${event is PointerScrollInertiaCancelEvent}');
            // In desktop app - reslut is false, false, true
            if(event is PointerScrollEvent) {
              double scrollDeltaY = event.scrollDelta.dy;
              print('scroll delta y $scrollDeltaY');
              setState(() {
                deltaY = scrollDeltaY;
              });
           }
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text('$deltaY'),
          ),
        ),
),

In web, event is PointerScrollEvent is true, so I can get event.scrollDelta.dy value. But in desktop, I could not get this value when I use Trackpad in mac or Apple Mouse.
Emmm... My question is how to get scrollDelta value when i change the mouse wheel in desktop?
Official Doc is here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html

Mouse with a scroll wheel can work.
